# how to navigate from one page to other page inside user defined function in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

This is my code.

```
Protected Sub testcall()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Default3.aspx", True)
End Sub
```

I want to navigate to Default3.aspx but it is not working.

Comment: What is not working ? Are you getting any error ? Exception, ???

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what it is doing? Is it throwing a 404 error? A 500 error? Can you see the sub being called in debugger mode?

Comment: no it is not throwing error or exception.but it is not going to the corresponding page

Answer (score 0):

Ya.sorry.Its working now.I had some problem in my visual studio 2010.Now this code is working perfectly.